# How to increment Bootstrap Progressbar with Model Method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, methods, progress-bar

[image]

For example, if **"Meditate"** is on **"Level 2"** with 5 `days_in_current_level` and 10 `days_left_in_current_level` (total 15 days) than how can the progressbar reflect those proportions with the blue spanning **33%** and the gray spanning **67%**?

**index.html.erb**

```
<td class="stretch">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="10" style="width: 60%;">
        <%= challenged.days_in_current_level %>
    </div>
    <div class="days-left"> 
        <%= challenged.days_left_in_current_level %> 
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

**habit.rb**

```
def days_in_current_level
    def n_days
        ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count do |date|
            committed_wdays.include? date.wday
        end - self.real_missed_days
    end

    case n_days
      when 0..9
        n_days
      when 10..24
        n_days-10
      when 25..44
        n_days-25
      when 45..69
        n_days-45
      when 70..99
        n_days-70
      else
        0 # No end
    end
end

def days_left_in_current_level
    def n_days
        ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count do |date|
            committed_wdays.include? date.wday
        end - self.real_missed_days
    end

    case n_days
      when 0..9
        10-n_days
      when 10..24
        25-n_days
      when 25..44
        45-n_days
      when 45..69
        70-n_days
      when 70..99
        100-n_days
      else
        0 # No end
    end
end
```

Please let me know if you need further explanation, code, or visuals to help you help me =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the width to:

```
days_in_current_level / (challenged.days_in_current_level + days_left_in_current_level ).to_f * 100
```

You get the percent by dividing the part with the total, and then multiply it with 100 to get it in the desired form.

In this case it calculates as:

```
5 / (5+10) * 100 = 5/15 * 100 = 33.333...
```

Example code:

```
# In your model
def progress_in_percent
  days_in_current_level / (challenged.days_in_current_level + days_left_in_current_level ).to_f * 100
end

# In your view
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="10" style="width: <%= challenged.progress_in_percent %>%;">
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you :) I had to revise your code a little for it to work for me. For some reason if I put `days_in_current_level / (challenged.days_in_current_level + days_left_in_current_level ) * 100` it comes up 0%?! So I did `100 / (days_in_current_level + days_left_in_current_level) * days_in_current_level` but that comes up as 30% instead of 33%, which isn't a big deal, but if you have a better solution I'm all ears :)

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com the reason for this is because all the numbers involved in the calculation are integers (whole numbers) so the division is done as integer rather than fractional division. Converting the denominator to a floating point number will change this to the desired behaviour:  `days_in_current_level / (challenged.days_in_current_level + days_left_in_current_level ).to_f * 100` which will give 33.33333333333333...

Comment: That thought was on the tip of my tongue. Thanks @mikej for pointing it out to me :)

Comment: Thank you @mikej for pointing out the rounding problem. The code has been updated now